# Magento2 set "in stock" when programmatically update qty

Tags: magento2, stock, out-of-stock, stock-status

I use this code to programmatically update the stock but status remain "out of stock". How to force Magento to set "in stock" when qty change from 0 to 1 or more ?

```
foreach($importArray as $line){ // pour chaque ligne
  $line = trim($line);
    $line = str_replace('"','',$line);
    $line = explode(';',$line);

  $sku = $line[1];
  $stockValue = $line[2];

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $stockRegistry = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

    if($product->getIdBySku($sku)) {
        $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
        $stockItem->setData('qty',$stockValue); //set updated quantity
        $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $qty, 'is_in_stock' => (bool)$qty]);
```

OR

```
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the second one works. just need to change the $qty by $stockValue in my script.

Comment: @urbansurfers - Happy to help. Keep helping :)